# Error code: 0xc0000225

Tags: windows-8.1, bcd

When I boot my Windows 8 laptop (see details below), it displays this message:

```
Recovery

Your PC needs to be repaired

A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed.

Error code: 0xc0000225

[ A text saying I should use recovery tools on my installation media to fix the issue. ]

Press Enter to try again

Press F8 for Start-up Settings

Press Esc for UEFI Firmware Settings
```

If I press Enter or F8, the central part of the message changes to:

```
The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.

File: \Windows\system32\winload.efi

Error code: 0xc0000225
```

I don't have a recovery disk and I have owned this computer for a year with no problems. All I did prior to this error was unistall avast and restart. I can only access UEFI Firmware Settings and have no clue what to do from there. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: I should add you might as well just place your HDD because that the root cause

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if your BCD (Boot Configuration Data) is corrupt, try:

- Insert your install disc
- Click on Repair your computer after you go through language, time
  etc.
- Select your Windows installation drive, which is usually C:, and
  click Next
- Choose Command Prompt when the System Recovery Options box appears
- Write the following command and press afterwards:

`bootrec /rebuildbcd`

---

Another possible cause is having the wrong partition set as active, try:

- Execute the following commands to see a list of all partitions on
  your disk:

`diskpart`

`list part`

Once you’ve determined which of the displayed partition needs to be active carry out the steps below to make the changes:

`select partition x`

`active`

`quit`

---

Failing this, try rebuilding your MBR using the following commands:

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /rebuildmbr
```