# Resized partitions on dual-boot with Ubuntu and Windows 10, Windows crashes on start up now

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot, gparted

I was trying to make more room on my Windows 10 partition, so I used Gparted Live to reduce partition size by 6GB of the Ubuntu boot. The Ubuntu will still boot, but the Windows partition boots with a blue, sad face screen. I get the windows error of 0xc0000225 when starting up. I did not move the left side of the Windows partition, only expanded it, and the partition had at least 60Gb of free space in it. There were no errors while partitioning the boots with Gparted Live.

Gparted Live cannot access the partition, although I can access Windows through Ubuntu and all files are accounted for. The Ubuntu grub for dual-boot does open up. Everything works fine, I can see the Windows partition, though when I open it, it crashes. This post is also posted on the askubuntu forum (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125476/resized-partitions-on-dual-boot-windows-10-wont-start-now) Both partitions are, I think, legacy BIOS, not UEFI.

I have tried to download a Windows 10 recovery disk onto my USB, though couldn't figure how to run it on ubuntu to use it for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix for that error code is mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/861999/error-code-0xc0000225). As for the recovery disk, you have to boot into advanced startup. [Here](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-access-advanced-startup-options-in-windows-10-or-8-2626229) is a link on how to do that. (Then just go through the menus until you find the recovery drive option)

I haven’t tested it for a recovery drive so this last method may not work, but going into the bios settings and manually making a boot option for your recovery usb may work? (I have no idea but everything is worth a try)

Lastly, [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options) guide from Microsoft recommends restarting while holding the shift key to get into advanced options. However, it assumes you have windows working, so I’m not sure if it will work from a non-windows restart. The Microsoft link also has instructions on what to do to use a recovery drive in advanced startup.

If none of those work and you get desperate, you can reinstall windows. After you boot from a windows instillation media (not the same as a recovery drive), windows may go “oh hey you have a broken version of windows, do you want to repair that and save your files in that?” However, it implies that it will wipe your Ubuntu. ( I think it will wipe it, but I can’t say for sure as I haven’t done it myself) On the flip side, using advanced install options will give you the ability to select your old windows partition for install, this saving your Ubuntu OS, but your files will be wiped (I have done this, and can verify it will wipe your files)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, problems kept compounding on top of one another. Once I finally got back to this problem, the Windows 10 recovery disk was indeed the answer. Just popped in there and "repaired" startup. Getting the iso downloaded and installed was the bugger. Thankyou for the answer nonetheless, something in your answer pushed me in the right direction.